# Custom text underline(using + and - symbols)

Tags: html, css, underline, text-decorations

I need implement custom text decoration, see image below:
[image: Custom text underline design]

It is simple to simulate `-` row with next styles:

```
color: red;
border-bottom: 3px dashed; // 3px - just for example, 2.5 also looks fine.
```

But I can't find out how to implement underline using `+` symbols.
Actually, I know that it is possible to have `background-image`, but it wouldn't work if text would be long.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

**UPD:**
Simple code snippet to play with:

```
<main>
    <h1>Here goes some heading <span class="deleted">and this is deleted</span></h1>
    <p>And here goes more text. <span class="added">This was inserted.</span> More text <span class="deleted">This was deleted</span></p>
</main>
```

Comment: Can u plz send me the html code?

Comment: I think you'll need some `JavaScript` for this to be accomplished.

Comment: @ths See first answer, w/out any JS and works like a charm!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with gradient like below:

```css
.deleted {
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right,red 0 4px,transparent 4px 6px) 
    bottom/100% 2px no-repeat;
}
.added {
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right,green 0px 1px,transparent 1px 5px) 
    bottom 0 left 2px/100% 5px no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(green,green) bottom 2px left 0/100% 1px no-repeat;
  padding-bottom:4px;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <h1>Here goes some heading <span class="deleted">and this is deleted</span></h1>
    <p>And here goes more text. <span class="added">This was inserted.</span> More text <span class="deleted">This was deleted</span></p>
</main>
```

If you want some spaces between the `+`

```css
.deleted {
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right,red 0 4px,transparent 4px 6px) 
    bottom/100% 2px no-repeat;
}
.added {
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right,green 0 1px,transparent 1px 7px) 
    bottom 0 left 2px/100% 5px no-repeat,
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right,green 0 5px,transparent 5px 7px) 
    bottom 2px left 0/100% 1px no-repeat;
  padding-bottom:4px;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <h1>Here goes some heading <span class="deleted">and this is deleted</span></h1>
    <p>And here goes more text. <span class="added">This was inserted.</span> More text <span class="deleted">This was deleted</span></p>
</main>
```

It will also work with multiline text:

```css
.deleted {
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right,red 0 4px,transparent 4px 6px) 
    bottom/100% 2px no-repeat;
}
.added {
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right,green 0 1px,transparent 1px 7px) 
    bottom 0 left 2px/100% 5px no-repeat,
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right,green 0 5px,transparent 5px 7px) 
    bottom 2px left 0/100% 1px no-repeat;
  padding-bottom:4px;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <h1>Here goes some heading <span class="deleted">and this is deleted</span></h1>
    <p>And here goes more text. <span class="added">This is long long long long long long long long long long text was inserted.</span> More text <span class="deleted">This was deleted</span></p>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the most performant solution.

```css
.added {
    color: green;
    position: relative;
}

.added:after {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" fill="green" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"%3E%3Cpath d="M24 10h-10v-10h-4v10h-10v4h10v10h4v-10h10z"/%3E%3C/svg%3E');
}
```

```html
<main>
    <h1>Here goes some heading <span class="deleted">and this is deleted</span></h1>
    <p>And here goes more text. <span class="added">This was inserted.</span> More text <span class="deleted">This was deleted</span>
    </p>
</main>
```

Comment: It would work with short strings, however, doesn't work with multiline text. See info in my question: `Actually, I know that it is possible to have background-image, but it wouldn't work if text would be long.`

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way would use javascript, but with css is possible to do, and would have to adapt to be responsive, you will create a content with many `+` and limit the size to occupy only the necessary, follow example

```css
.add:after{
  content: "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++";
  color: green;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  top: 17%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.after-75:after{
  width:75%;
}

.add{
width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="add after-75">We need underline</h1>
```